# Google Analytics receiving data from Chrome's "Incognito Window" only

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have this educational website in which I am trying to track the visits: http://educa03.org (you can see that the google analytics code is set correctly inside the head of the doc as it states in the google analytics "how to").

In the google analytics page I can see:

```
Status: Receiving Data
```

Through the "real time" tracking page in google analytics I can see two different situations depending on how I access to the site (using Chrome) :

**Case A**

1. Open incognito window
2. Login to the google analytics account
3. Go to the site from this incognito window
4. "Real time" tracks my visit: OK!

**Case B**

Same setup but in point #3 I go to the site from a different (not incognito) window. "Real time" does NOT track my visit.

In this case B I have a console message not seen in case A:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "about:blank"
```

This is the line to blame:

```
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
```

---

I tried using Google Analytics Debugger with no success:

- It can not be used in Incognito Mode
- In the "not incognito mode", the only message seen in the console is the error shown above.

So I feel locked with nothing else in mind to try next.

Comment: Perhaps check if JavaScript is enabled or disabled in private mode.

Comment: Also check if you have any ad / privacy blockers installed in non-incognito mode.

Comment: That was it @MisterPhilip, thank you very much! That didn't even cross my mind... I was using Disconnect chrome extension, and sure enough it was blocking google analytics.